# How should I neutralize restored plaster walls?

Tags: paint, plaster

I have made half a dozen plaster patches within my home remodeling, each about 30-40 sq ft.  The plaster goes over brick, so not lath.  It was a hell of a job but still simpler than framing walls and hanging drywall.

I used the old-fashioned plaster recipe:  for the inner two coats (it needed that many coats to be flush with the old plaster bordering it because the old plaster is 3/4" thick) I used 2.5x masonry sand and 1x hydraulic lime (by a company called Virginia Lime Works).  For the finish coat I used 1.5x really fine sand (by Quickrete) and 1x the same hydraulic lime.

In preparation for painting, I was told that before applying primer, the presence of lime in the plaster required neutralizing.  I am not sure about this so I am asking to confirm.  In addition, are there better solutions to neutralizing than vinegar?

Answer (score 2):

This thread [at Contractor Talk regarding priming/painting new lime plaster](http://www.contractortalk.com/f8/painting-new-plaster-26809/) has multiple good tips:

Wait 2-3 mos (until plaster is fully white), neutralize (vinegar in water was mentioned) and prime with an alkyd primer.